# maven-surefire-plugin rerunFailingTestsCount not running tests immediately

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the following configuration for **maven-failsafe-plugin**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <runOrder>failedfirst</runOrder>
        <rerunFailingTestsCount>2</rerunFailingTestsCount>
        <!-- .. additional configuration removed -->
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Ideally I would like the failing tests to run immediately upon failing, but this is not what I am observing. I see something like this happening:

- GoodTestOne passes
- BadTestTwo fails
- GoodTestThree passes
- GoodTestFour passes
- BadTestTwo fails
- BadTestTwo fails

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to configure failsafe to do this:

- GoodTestOne passes
- BadTestTwo fails
- BadTestTwo fails
- BadTestTwo fails
- ...

I am building a TestExecutionListener to abort all tests after a single test has failed the configured allowed number of times, but given that it's running through our entire test suite (which takes almost 20 minutes) before re-running failed tests, it defeats the purpose.

I realize that "skipAfterFailureCount" provides this functionality, but we are using JUnit 5 and [this is not yet supported](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/featurematrix.html).

Comment: It is not possible. You could consider contributing some exploratory work to make it possible https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1880#issuecomment-1857647581

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not optimistic that any suggestion or proposed implementation will get worked on in a reasonable time frame. Your link illustrates this well, since it's for a thread going back to 2019 and is not yet closed.

Comment: That's mostly because no one is willing to put in the work. I've had 13 PRs merged since 2021. So things definitely get done. And personally I don't care that much about stopping test runs early. I rather fix the flakes. And I suspect the same is true for the members of the JUnit team. You and presumably your company have that interest so the burden falls on you.

Comment: That said, you could probably hack something by globally registering a `ExecutionCondition` extension and have that check some static state in your test execution listener.

Comment: Thank you. I will explore using an ExecutionCondition.